# Perché si dice "lo penso" e non "gli penso"?

Tags: verbs, grammar, pronouns, particles

Il verbo pensare si usa con un oggetto indiretto:

> pensare a qualcuno/qualcosa.

Ma, ho notato che il suo oggetto si sostituisce con il pronome diretto "lo" oppure la particella "ci",  ma non con il pronome indiretto "gli".

Perché "gli" non è usato invece di "lo" (un uso che dovrebbe essere sbagliato)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Riassunto:

- In *lo penso* si usa il verbo *pensare* transitivo e *lo* ha la funzione di complemento oggetto.
- In *ci penso* si usa il verbo *pensare* intransitivo e *ci* ha la funzione di complemento locativo ("indica il luogo, reale o metaforico, verso cui è rivolto il pensiero").
- *Pensare* non regge un complemento di termine: per questa ragione i pronomi *gli* o *le* non si possono usare con questo verbo.

---

Come puoi vedere in [questo articolo dell'Accademia della Crusca](https://accademiadellacrusca.it/it/consulenza/il-verbo-pensare-con-i-pronomi-atoni/), il verbo
[*pensare*](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/pensare) può essere
sia transitivo che intransitivo.

L'uso che hai riportato nella domanda

> pensare a qualcuno/qualcosa

corrisponde al verbo intransitivo.

Se invece dico

> Penso che, su Italian.SE, votare sia molto importante

sto facendo un uso transitivo del verbo. Tu potresti rispondere usando il pronome *lo* per sostituire il complemento oggetto

> Lo penso anch'io.

Potresti anche dire

> Anch'io la penso così

usando il pronome femminile *la* come complemento oggetto.

L'articolo citato spiega che questi due verbi, *pensare* transitivo e *pensare* intransitivo hanno significati leggermente diversi:

> Anche a livello semantico ci sono sottili differenze tra *pensare* transitivo che viene così definito, nel *Grande Dizionario italiano dell'uso* curato da Tullio De Mauro: "raffigurare con la mente, esaminare con il pensiero, anche escogitare, inventare" e *pensare* intransitivo, che invece assume il significato di "avere il pensiero rivolto a qualcuno o a qualcosa", con una connotazione affettiva che nel primo caso è meno rilevante.

Perché quando si usa il verbo intransitivo in una frase come, per esempio,

> Penso al mio fidanzato

non diventa "*gli penso"? Il punto chiave per rispondere a questa domanda è spiegato all'inizio dell'articolo:

> Il verbo *pensare* può essere [...] intransitivo e reggere un complemento indiretto, che però non è un complemento di termine, ma un locativo.

Il pronome *gli* sostituisce un complemento di termine, ma nelle espressioni

> pensare a qualcuno/qualcosa

"a qualcuno" o "a qualcosa" non hanno la funzione di complemento di termine, ma di locativo ("pensare a qualcuno/qualcosa" vuol dire "avere il pensiero rivolto a qualcuno/qualcosa"). Quindi, "al mio fidanzato" nella frase precedente non è complemento di termine e, per questa ragione, non può essere sostituito dal pronome *gli*.

Questo spiega anche perché invece si può usare la particella *ci* con *pensare* intransitivo, come hai fatto notare nella domanda:

> Nella forma intransitiva il verbo *pensare* è seguito da un complemento retto dalla preposizione *a*, complemento che però, contrariamente a quello che potrebbe sembrare, non è un complemento di termine, ma un complemento che indica il luogo, reale o metaforico, verso cui è rivolto il pensiero. Nel passaggio dalla forma tonica che segue il verbo, tipo "sto pensando a lei", alla forma atona che invece precede il verbo, proprio in virtù del fatto che si tratta di un locativo, viene inserito il clitico *ci*, quindi "ci sto pensando", anche quando l'oggetto del pensiero sia una persona.

Nello stesso modo

> Penso al mio fidanzato

diventerebbe

> Ci penso.

Non è una frase tanto comune, ma si potrebbe anche dire usando *pensare* transitivo

> Penso il mio fidanzato

che avrebbe il senso di "raffiguro con la mente il mio fidanzato" (l'articolo dell'Accademia della Crusca riporta l'esempio "penso lui ancora giovane e snello"). In questo caso, "il mio fidanzato" è complemento oggetto e si può sostituire con il pronome *lo* in questo modo:

> Lo penso.

Comment: Veramente [penso che votare sia molto importante su questo sito](https://italian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1461/) :).

Comment: Credo che la domanda sia più orientata a capire perché si dice *penso a lui* oppure *lo penso* (diciamo riferendosi al fidanzato), ma non \**gli penso*.

Comment: Si veda https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?corpus=33&content=gli+penso%2Clo+penso%2Cpenso+a+lui&smoothing=3&year_end=2019&year_start=1600&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgli%20penso%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clo%20penso%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpenso%20a%20lui%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Non capisco bene cosa vuoi dire, @egreg. "Penso al fidanzato" dovrebbe essere "ci penso" perché "al fidanzato" ha la funzione di locativo e non di complemento di termine.

Comment: Si può dire “ci penso”, ma anche “lo penso”. Come risulta dall'ngram, “gli penso” non si dice.

Comment: Sì, @egreg: questo è quello che si spiega nella risposta, no? "Lo penso" corrisponde a *pensare* transitivo, "ci penso" corrisponde a *pensare* intransitivo.

Comment: @egreg: Vuoi dire che forse dovrei aggiungere un esempio di uso transitivo del tipo "penso il mio fidanzato" nel senso di "raffiguro con la mente il mio fidanzato", che diventerebbe "lo penso"? Ancora non riesco a capire cos'è quello che manca nella risposta.

Comment: Boh! Se è questo... cerco di aggiungerlo, @egreg.

Comment: @Charo, perfetto grazie mille.